# Attendance Database with Excessive Absence Alert

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ms-access

I have a pretty standard attendance database design, but I want to be alerted when a student hits a certain number of absences.  I was thinking to use a point system where each absence would accumulate a certain number of points (tracked on the student table itself) it would throw a message.  The DB is currently in Access 2003, but I'm probably going to move it to MS SQL Server in the near future.

Here's my design idea, just want to make sure it's logical and normalized.  I've bolded the columns I'm most concerned about.

tblAttendance -

- PK AttendanceID
- FK EventID
- FK StudentID
- Date AttendanceDate

tblEventEnrollment -

- PK EventEnrollmentID
- FK StudentID
- FK EventID

tblEvents -

- PK EventID
- FK EventType
- nvarchar EventName
- FK EventLeader

tblEventTypes -

- PK EventTypeID
- nvarchar EventType
- **int PointsIfMissed**

tblStudents -

- PK StudentID
- nvarchar FistName
- nvarchar LastName
- **int CurrentPoints**

**EDIT**
Using a CurrentPoints column in tblStudents is based on two factors:

1. To avoid excessive joins/aggregation.  One student may have 10 events a day, 3650 a year, and over say 10 years 36,000+ event attendance records to be checked to get his score. (I have not done any tests to see the actual performance impact once the data set gets big)
2. To allow me to reset the points.  I also considered using a Date LastPointResetDate column in tblStudents and then using a query along these lines to calculate the score, I was just worried about performance (keep in mind I want to check this with every new attendance record):

   SELECT SUM(tblEventTypes.PoinsIfMissed) AS CurrentPoints FROM tblAttendance INNER JOIN tblEvents ON tblAttendance.EventID=tblEvents.EventID INNER JOIN tblEventTypes ON tblEventTypes.EventTypeID=tblEvents.EventTypeID WHERE tblAttendance.AttendanceDate > tblStudents.LastPointResetDate.

Comment: Do you intend that some absences will earn more points than others?  If not, a point system seems ... um ... pointless; just count the number of absences. Either way, I think you should derive the score with a query whenever you need it, rather than storing the computed value in a table.

Comment: @HansUp Yes, every event type will have a unique absence score.  So for example missing class is worth more than missing weekend studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a quick glance, why does events have :

```
FK EventType
```

Rather than

```
FK EventTypeID
```

It seems to me that a student can only miss an event if they are enrolled for that event, so rather than int CurrentPoints in the student table, get the points from a LEFT JOIN from enrollment to attendance to find the missed events.

Comment: FK EventType was an error, thanks!  Also, see my edit for reasons why I wanted a CurrentPoints column.

Comment: @just There are a few problems with a calculated field, especially in a case like this where, presumably, an argument can be present as to why absence should be forgiven. You may even need a forgiven table or phantom attendance :) , depending on your rules, because to simply reduce the count without some note seems like a dangerous idea. 36,000 does not seem like that much for SQL Server.

Comment: I could add code that subtracts points when an absence is forgiven if I wanted to keep it in my table.  I know it's not 100% normalized that way, but considering the number of queries I'm still worried.  If I log attendance for 500 students at one event, that's 500 queries of ~15,000 records each assuming they all have 2.5 years of data (7.5 mil total rows).  If I keep it in the table, it's a single query of one column.

Comment: I am playing devil's advocate, I think, at this stage. The problem is "but I'm probably going to move it to MS SQL Server in the near future", if that is the case, it may be possible to take advantage of calculated columns.

Comment: How would I use a calculated column here?  MS says calculated column definition must come from the same table (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx).

Comment: I am by no means an expert, but something on these http://www.novicksoftware.com/udfofweek/Vol2/T-SQL-UDF-Vol-2-Num-1-computed-column.htm lines, perhaps.